# PHP: Convert between array 1 deep to multi deep json

Tags: php, json, explode

I keep data 1 deep like this (Maybe for keep in DB)

```
$data = [
    "games" => "",
    "games>sport" => "",
    "games>sport>enabled" => true,
    "feature" => "",
    "feature>register" => "",
    "feature>register>enabled" => true,
    "contact" => "",
    "contact>tel" => "",
    "contact>tel>lang" => "th",
    "contact>tel>number" => "012345678"
];
```

And Then convert To json

Result:

```
{
  "games": {
    "sport":
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "feature": {
    "register": {
      "enabled": true,
      "captcha": true
    }
  },
  "contact": {
    "tel": {
      "lang": "th",
      "number": "012345678"
    }
  }
```

### }

**Edit**: The guy that tag this as duplicate to article that not event close. I have to find my way

**This is my own answer.**

```
$col = [];
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    $ex = explode(">", $key);
    $cnt = count($ex);

    if (count($ex) > 5) { die('Maximum deep is 5'); }
    if ($cnt == 1) { $col[$ex[0]] = $val;  }
    if ($cnt == 2) { $col[$ex[0]][$ex[1]] = $val;  }
    if ($cnt == 3) { $col[$ex[0]][$ex[1]][$ex[2]] = $val; }
    if ($cnt == 4) { $col[$ex[0]][$ex[1]][$ex[2]][$ex[3]] = $val; }
    if ($cnt == 5) { $col[$ex[0]][$ex[1]][$ex[2]][$ex[3]][$ex[4]] = $val; }
}
die(json_encode($col));
```

Comment: Can you include any code you have tried so far?

Comment: What should it do if the original array has `"games" => "non-empty string"`?

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I could use some sign instead, i edit the question.

Comment: If you can only use the stored data after it is decoded from json to array, I recommend that you store it as a json string instead of that `>` separated mess.